# bootstrap navbar color not changing

Tags: html, css

i want this bootstrap navbar background color to be clear without any background color.

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
     
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
            
           
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
              

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Designs
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
            
                 
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="border: 1px solid #0F0436;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
           
          </ul>
    
        </div>
      </nav>
```

i have tried this css but its not working, also i tried it with !important since bootstrap has its own css but same thing :/

```css
.navbar .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-light .bg-light {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    transition: 0.5s;    
    text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write any css. Use Bootstraps `bg-transparent` class for this.

In your HTML replace `bg-light` with `bg-transparent`

**Current**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
```

**New**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
```

Comment: thank you, but now i did this .navbar-collapse.collapse  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0; 
 
  }
 and i cant see mouse pointer on them

Comment: You wanted to have the navbar clear - right? So perhaps `bg-white` is what you are looking for. Try that instead of `bg-transparent`.

Comment: bg-transparent is what i want, but when fixed the navbar and align it to right the cursor pointer is not showing on them

Comment: Ok. You don't need to have your css. Use bootstrap's `sticky-top` or `fixed-top `. `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-transparent">`

Answer (score 1):

I see that your navbar has the class of **bg-light**. This class gives white color to the navbar. To make the navbar transparent, you have to add **bg-transparent** as the class. Or you can  just clear the class of bg-light. 
**Your code** --

```html
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
```

**Change it to (if you want to make it transparent) --**

```html
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent" >
```